# MarkerClusters from Fuson Table in Google Map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am mapping 20k records from Google Fusion table using standard circle. I would like to group them using MarkerClusters. Because there is filtering and search occuring, I am not sure where to place the var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers); code.

[Here is the map.](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/NewYorkCityFilms/b/)

Code snippet where markers are created:

```
//*New Fusion Tables Requirement* API key. found at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
  //*Important* this key is for demonstration purposes. please register your own.
  googleApiKey:       "AIzaSyDj8qostHt2L3aetpO_LuipyS6YvfeZOFA",

  //name of the location column in your Fusion Table.
  //NOTE: if your location column name has spaces in it, surround it with single quotes
  //example: locationColumn:     "'my location'",
  locationColumn:     "geo_coordinates",

  map_centroid:       new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127,-74.0059), //center that your map defaults to
  locationScope:      "new york city",      //geographical area appended to all address searches
  recordName:         "result",       //for showing number of results
  recordNamePlural:   "results",

  searchRadius:       805,            //in meters ~ 1/2 mile
  defaultZoom:        13,             //zoom level when map is loaded (bigger is more zoomed in)
  addrMarkerImage:    'images/blue_pin.png',
  currentPinpoint:    null,


  initialize: function() {
    $( "#result_count" ).html("");

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: MapsLib.defaultZoom,
      center: MapsLib.map_centroid,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,


            };  
    map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0],myOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    map.setOptions({ styles : styles });

    // maintains map centerpoint for responsive design
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        MapsLib.calculateCenter();
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(MapsLib.map_centroid);
    });

    MapsLib.searchrecords = null;
```

Comment: Your Markers are in a FusionTablesLayer.  You need to remove that and query the table to create native Google Map Javascript API v3 Markers if you want to use the MarkerClusterer.

Comment: @geocodezip  - so don't use Fusion Tables? Not sure how you mean.

Comment: Or query the table for the data to create the markers.  Don't use FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: @geocodezip  thanks. do you know of an example? my who app is based on the fusion table.